# Python negative regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string such as:

```
s = "The code for the product is A8H4DKE3SP93W6J and you can buy it here."
```

The text in this string will not always be in the same format, it will be dynamic, so I can't do a simple find and replace to obtain the product code.

I can see that:

```
re.sub(r'A[0-9a-zA-Z_]{14} ', '', s)
```

will get ride of the product code. How do I go about doing the opposite of this, i.e. deleting all of the text, apart from the product code? The product code will always be a 15 character string, starting with the letter A.

I have been racking my brain and Googling to find a solution, but can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html#re.findall)

Comment: Just extract what you want to keep and discard the rest of the string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regex findall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752551/python-regex-findall)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of substituting the rest of the string, use [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) to search for the product number:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s = "The code for the product is A8H4DKE3SP93W6J and you can buy it here."

In [3]: re.search(r"A[0-9a-zA-Z_]{14}", s).group()
Out[3]: 'A8H4DKE3SP93W6J'
```

Answer (score 0):

In regex, you can match on the portion you want to keep for substituting by using braces around the pattern and then referring to it in the sub-pattern with backslash followed by the index for that matching portion. In the code below, "(A[0-9A-Za-z_]{14})" is the portion you want to match, and you can substitute in the resulting string using "\1".

```
re.sub(r'.*(A[0-9A-Za-z_]{14}).*', r'\1', s)
```