# How do you write a regex in python which picks out all strings beginning with a specific number

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get this regex to pick out both 7gh and 7ui but I can only get it to pick out the first one.  If anyone knows how to amend the regex such that it also picks out 7ui, I would seriously appreciate it. I should also point out that I mean strings separated by a space.

```
b = re.search(r'^7\w+','7gh ghj 7ui')
c = b.group()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regex findall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752551/python-regex-findall)

Comment: ^essentially, use `findall` instead of `search`

Comment: What about `a7b`? Both solutions would currently pick it as `7b` - is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `^` and use `findall()` :

```
>>> re.findall(r'7\w+','7gh ghj 7ui')
['7gh', '7ui']
```

Comment: that doesn't work.  That only captures the first string with 7

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `^` (start of string anchor) and use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) to find *all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string*:

```
import re
res = re.findall(r'7\w+','7gh ghj 7ui')
print(res)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/BIoYET)

If you need to get these substrings as *whole words*, enclose the pattern with a word boundary, `\b`:

```
res = re.findall(r'\b7\w+\b','7gh ghj 7ui')
```

Comment: difference of few sec :)

Comment: They probably want a word boundary in there to avoid picking up `bob7something`...

Comment: @akashkarothiya Yeah, but I think OP might need further tweaking, so, I also suggest a word boundary.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew much appreciated :) helpful

Comment: @bobsmith76 you should also consider Wikter's 2nd method for future reference, using `\b`, Please see

Answer (score 0):

You may find it easier to just not use regex

```
[s for s in my_string.split() if s.startswith('7')]
```

Comment: No, I'm trying to understand how regexes work.  I'm not trying to get something done.