# How to count how many times a text appears in webpage using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to count how many times an string "Airport" appears on an website. I tried to use Request Module , BS4 etc. and tried to scrap data from there, but the REST response returns a very concise xml which actually does not contain the text in it. Find_Element_By_Link_Text method also does not work here as the string "Airport" is part of the texts shown on the page. Is there any method that I can use to count the number of occurrences of the text "Airport" on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use browser.page_source, convert it to a string and use regular expression findall.

[Python Selenium accessing HTML source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861775/python-selenium-accessing-html-source)

[Python regex findall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752551/python-regex-findall)

Answer (score -1):

why don't you use some javascript?

get all the html code/text

```
var wholeText = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

then split by "Airport"

```
var repeat = wholeText.split("Airport");
```

finally count the elements in your repeat array

```
total = repeat.length -1
```

this should give you all the airports in the whole code (including backend)

another easy approach is just use your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and find the occurrences manually